# asp.net multiple web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, webforms, web-config

I have multiple site bindings(1 for each country) defined in IIS 7.5 for my asp.net webforms application. I would like to use a different web.config for each sitebinding. Is this possible and if yes how can I do this?